# How do I make JDK 7 default jave to be used on Mac OSX 10.9+?

Tags: java, macos

By default, if you install the Oracle JDK, it will not be used as the default java environment.

All the system symlinks from /usr/bin/java* do forward to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current instead of CurrentJDK.

How can I change these, is there any script that can change default java?

Comment: That's odd. As soon as I install an Oracle JDK, it becomes the default on my system. What does `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` reveal?

Comment: As an aside, the symlinks always point to the system JavaVM framework as it's actually a wrapper for launching the appropriate version of java

Answer (score 1):

Check the [instructions of Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/bobby/entry/switching_jdks_on_mac). You can use `Applications -> Utilities -> Java` to switch the default JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Set your JAVA_HOME to your JDK 7.

Check this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/